# update apache 2.2 to apache 2.4 on centos 6.4 - 64bit

Tags: apache

Hi please tell me process for update apache 2.2 to 2.4

I command yum install httpd and install it 2.2

OS- centos 6.4 Final to 64 bits

Comment: This is probably better answered at http://serverfault.com

Comment: Or [superuser](http://superuser.com) if it's not a professional system. :)

Answer (score 1):

The base install of CentOS is built with the idea of stability in mind over getting the latest version. See http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-472ce8446ebcfc82ca1800f775ba0e629ac835c7

For this reason, Apache 2.4 is not available via the standard yum repositories.

However, you can do a manual install (which I try to avoid), or use a repository such as the one created by Jan Kaluza that allows you to install an instance of Apache 2.4 . For more information, see http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/10/24/apache-httpd-2-4-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6/

There may be some other good repositories that you could use to get a clean version of 2.4 installed but this is what I know about.

Answer (score -1):

Do `yum list httpd*` from the output select the version 2.4 archive and install it using `yum install NAME`

Comment: yum list httpd*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.edatel.net.co
 * extras: mirror.edatel.net.co
 * updates: mirror.edatel.net.co
Error: No matching Packages to list

Comment: Only view apache 2.2, please help, tnks

Comment: correct commands is:
yum list all httpd